# How to replace the element with ng-transclude

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Is it possible to replace the element with `ng-transclude` on it rather than the entire template element?

**HTML:**

```
<div my-transcluded-directive>
    <div>{{someData}}</div>
</div>
```

**Directive:**

```
return {
    restrict:'A',
    templateUrl:'templates/my-transcluded-directive.html',
    transclude:true,
    link:function(scope,element,attrs)
    {

    }
};
```

**my-transcluded-directive.html:**

```
<div>
    <div ng-transclude></div>
    <div>I will not be touched.</div>
</div>
```

What I am looking for is a way to have `<div>{{someData}}</div>` replace `<div ng-transclude></div>`. What currently happens is the transcluded HTML is placed *inside* the `ng-transclude` div element.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I think the best solution would probably be to create your own transclude-replace directive that would handle this. But for a quick and dirty solution to your example you could essentially manually place the result of the transclusion where you want:

**my-transcluded-directive.html:**

```
<div>
    <span>I WILL BE REPLACED</span>
    <div>I will not be touched.</div>
</div>
```

**Directive:**

```
return {
    restrict:'A',
    templateUrl:'templates/my-transcluded-directive.html',
    transclude:true,
    link:function(scope,element,attrs,ctrl, transclude)
    {
         element.find('span').replaceWith(transclude());
    }
};
```

Comment: For me `element` finds `div[my-transcluded-directive]`, not the template.

Comment: @LittleBigBot if you want to post a fiddle I'll take a look

Comment: Note that you need to compile the contents if there are some directives: `.replaceWith($compile(transclude())(scope))`

Comment: Thanks. This `replace` trick won't work, if some child directive has dependency on the parent.

Comment: Another snippet of code that can help in some situations is `element.find('span').replaceWith(transclude().clone());`

Comment: @Jonny Henry Briggs your fiddle doesn't appear to mantain "<div>I will not be touched.</div>" element. 
Your compiled doesn't report that element. So something is wrong :(

Answer (score 30):

It's easy to create a `ng-transclude-replace` directive, here is a copycat of the original `ng-transclude`.

```
directive('ngTranscludeReplace', ['$log', function ($log) {
              return {
                  terminal: true,
                  restrict: 'EA',

                  link: function ($scope, $element, $attr, ctrl, transclude) {
                      if (!transclude) {
                          $log.error('orphan',
                                     'Illegal use of ngTranscludeReplace directive in the template! ' +
                                     'No parent directive that requires a transclusion found. ');
                          return;
                      }
                      transclude(function (clone) {
                          if (clone.length) {
                              $element.replaceWith(clone);
                          }
                          else {
                              $element.remove();
                          }
                      });
                  }
              };
          }]);
```

PS:you can also check [this link](http://gogoout.github.io/angular-directives-utils/#/api/ng-directives-utils.transcludeReplace) to see the difference between the `ng-transclude`

Comment: Thank you! I've been searching for a viable solution that works with a directive that uses transclusion but is also a part of an ng-repeat. The accepted solution works but not with ng-repeat. I am thinking it has to do with `terminal: true`. The best part is that the user of this code doesn't have to know it for it to work :)

Comment: Brilliant. Just what I wanted thank you very much. IMHO this should be the default behaviour for transclude rather than leaving empty, useless extra nesting Dom elements everywhere!

Answer (score 4):

this works in Angular 1.4.9 (and prob earlier too)

```
return {
      restrict: 'E',
      replace: true,
      template: '<span data-ng-transclude></span>',
      transclude: true,
      link: function (scope, el, attrs) .........
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have to support IE and Edge you can use `display:contents` in your css. That will destroy the wrapper on the level of css.

You can read more about this new display propertie here:
https://css-tricks.com/get-ready-for-display-contents/

Current browser support (hope to see Edge support in the future):
https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-display-contents