# In an AngularJs directive, can I append html with transclude

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-transclude

I would like to use a directive to convert this

```
<div x-my-input>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="foobar" data-ng-model="foobar">
</div>
```

to this

```
<div x-my-input class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="foobar" data-ng-model="foobar">
    <span class="input-group-addon blur-icon">
        <span class="glyphicons glyphicons-keyboard-wireless"></span>
    </span>
</div>
```

I also want to add blur and focus triggers. This is what I have at the moment.

```
.directive("myInput", function() {
    return {
        restrict: "EAC",
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        scope: true,
        template: '<div class="input-group">' +
            '<ng-transclude></ng-transclude>' +
            '<span class="input-group-addon blur-icon">' +
            '<span class="js-hide-icon glyphicons-top glyphicons glyphicons-keyboard-wireless"></span>' +
            '</span>',
            '</div>',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl, $timeout) {
            $timeout(function() {
                var $inputElement = element.find('input').first();
                $inputElement.focus(function() {
                    $(".form-submit, .nav-bar").fadeOut(150);
                }).blur(function() {
                    $(".form-submit, .nav-bar").fadeIn(150);
                });
            });
        }
    };
})
```

Functionally it works, but the html it creates is this

```
<div class="input-group ng-scope" x-my-input="">
    <ng-transclude>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="foobar" data-ng-model="foobar">
    </ng-transclude>
    <span class="input-group-addon blur-icon">
        <span class="glyphicons glyphicons-keyboard-wireless"></span>
    </span>
</div>
```

How can I get the **input** to be wrapped with the **div** and also have the **span** inside the **div** after the **input**?

Comment: if you are asking how to remove the `ng-transclude` element, that isn't possible, because that would break the directive's ability to update.

Comment: I don't mind having ng-transclude in there, but I need to have the input and span as direct children of the div

Comment: it can't be the direct child and transcluded at the same time.  however, you can create a custom directive to use instead of transclude, to do what you want.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21092885/how-to-replace-the-element-with-ng-transclude

Comment: okay, I might also try to use jquery append() in the link function and move the span from template to there

Comment: it feels a lot like you are falling outside angular a bit here; between suggesting a jquery alternative and the idea that you are concerned about the hierarchy of the HTML (presumably because some other logic requires it) are pretty big indicators that things other than angular are at play.